# Rails Devise - Add more number of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have been working on Devise and I tried to find a way to add more database attributes to the users table from devise. But it seems devise supports only `email` and `password` fields.

Is it possible to add more fields to the devise, so devise can validate to and save it to the users table on `create`, `update` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can add more fields by using migration.

I hope below link is help full to you.

http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Comment: This is a great tutorial for answering this question. well done.

Comment: Nice tutorial, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Checkout their documentation. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
and search the page for "strong parameters" that should show you mostly what you're looking for. 
an example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :avatar, :latitude, :longitude ) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :first_name, :last_name, :age, :about_me, :gender, :avatar, :latitude, :longitude ) }
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, after posting this question i get to know about this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can like below I did for `first_name`, `last_name`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```